# WCF Json Parsing

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

Is there a direct method for parsing WCF Json in objective C. If so could anyone please provide a suitable link or code for it. Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link that demonstrate the counsumption of JSON services in objective C. http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c

Basically calling a WCF json service requires you to Build JSON wcf service first and then consume it using URL in your Objective C Code.

For calling a JSON webservice from iPhone , there is an iPhone JSON Library and I think it's just the thing you need. It's called JSON-Framework , a strict JSON generator and parser for Objective-C.

You can download it from Google-Code:
http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

And here I find a detailed tutorial about How to Use JSON Over HTTP On the iPhone for you:

Tutorial: JSON Over HTTP On The iPhone
http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/

Also please check [IPhone consuming restful WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004553/iphone-consuming-restful-wcf-service?rq=1) answer for consuming WCF Rest Service in Objective C for Iphone application development.

Comment: hi @Kiron i done my WCF json parsing with this code visit my ans of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583667/xml-parsing-error-while-using-wcf-framework-for-web-services/12584067#12584067

Comment: I would add that you probably should consider using Apple's JSON parser, `NSJSONSerialization` instead. It's faster and is supported without adding additional external libraries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356842/how-to-use-nsjsonserialization